# What was the Rebel victory prior to A New Hope?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

In the *Star Wars: Episode IV: A New Hope* opening crawl, it says the Rebels won their first victory. The victory was in some battle that happened before the start of the film. From that battle, they retrieved the Death Star plans.  What battle was that? Do we have any information on what happened during the battle?

Comment: I would have thought that would have been the battle where the rebels get the plans...

Comment: Think about this little detail... their FIRST victory. Which causes the Empire to select Alderaan as their demonstration for the death star's weapon, as well as tracking the droids to Tatooine and the murder of a few Jawas and Luke's aunt and uncle. Apart from that, what else has the original trilogy revealed as evidence the Empire is evil? Everything the Empire does is a direct result of the rebels' actions. Had they not stolen the plans, would anyone have been deliberately hurt? Just sayin, maybe the Empire isn't the enemy in those movies.

Comment: @KaiQing Building a Death Star doesn't sound like a nice thing to do.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Neither does launching 100 tomahawk missiles into syria for no real reason. We don't know what the real intentions were for project stardust as they call it in rogue one. But not unlike our dumb human asses, it seems operations of extreme tragedy can be "justified" if spun the right way. All I'm suggesting is it's all cause and effect in star wars. But the cause starts with the Rebels striking first. So who is the real bad guy?

Comment: I think we're pretty sure what the real intentions were.  From the first movie: Grand Moff Tarkin: The regional governors now have direct control over their territories. Fear will keep the local systems in line. Fear of this battle station.

Comment: *"what else has the original trilogy revealed as evidence the Empire is evil?"* - Genocide isn't naughty enough for you?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The 'victory' referenced in the opening crawl did, indeed, occur just prior to the start of Episode IV.

A small team of Rebels headed by Jyn Erso and Cassan Andor infiltrated an Imperial data storage facility (located within a significant military base) while a number of other volunteers staged an assault.

During this mission, they were largely successful, managing to secure and transmit the plans for the Death Star to orbiting Rebel ships.

> The 'victory' was a Pyrrhic one, as virtually everyone on the assault and infiltration force was captured or killed, and several starships were destroyed.

---

Prior to the new Disney movies and the exclusion of the novel canon to the new 'Legends' flag, this had been the canon answer:

The events are detailed in the novella "Interlude at Darkknell", which you can find in the book [*Tales of the New Republic*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0553578820).

The story features several people from Stackpole's *X-wing* series, several years before that series (obviously).

More info can be found at the [Wookieepedia article on the plans](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Death_Star_plans/Legends).

Comment: If you have played the original X-Wing game for PC, you get to play through several missions surrounding the acquisition of the plans and the escape of Princess Leia with the plans aboard the Tantive IV before the Empire catches up with her at Tatooine at the start of the movie.

Comment: unfortunately, games are pretty low in the canon - but I think that this hasn't been overridden by any books.

Comment: @HorusKol - licensed games (aside from alternate endings) are C canon, just as books are. (except some really old RPGs)

Comment: This answer is no longer canon and requires an update.

Comment: @RogueJedi - Updated to reference the new canon.  Thanks!

Comment: The definition of a pyrrhic victory is one that was won at too great a cost to have been worthwhile for the victor.   As the victory directly resulted in passing the data on to those who ultimately used it to destroy the Death Star, and all those on the mission were willing to die for this purpose, their victory was NOT pyrrhic.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson - the victory was absolutely a Pyrrhic one.  In the course of the mission, the Rebellion lost a large number of well-trained people and several of their limited starships.  Yes, it enabled the destruction of the Death Star, but that was the result of a newly-recruited space wizard that the Rebellion could NOT have anticipated.  Just because a Hail Mary pass worked doesn't mean the mission was any less costly.

Comment: +1 A quibble: I do not think the word '[Pyrrhic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrhic_victory)' means what you think it means: the Rebellion won the battle at Yavin because of the successful mission in *Rogue One*, and arguably this set the stage for the success of the battle at Endor as well. The Rebel Alliance and their New Republic, despite setbacks leading to Endor, and despite the lingering efforts of the First Order are the long-run victors in the Rebels vs. Empire conflict. 'Pyrrhic victory' does not mean 'some of our soldiers died'.

Comment: @Lexible -  no, a 'Pyrrhic victory' means that so many losses were suffered that the victory was also a catastrophe.  If not for the unforseeable presence of Luke at the Battle of Yavin, the Rebellion would have been destroyed.  The losses sustained in R1 left the Rebellion with too few starships to evacuate or engage in a standard battle.  The entire thing was millimeters from being a disaster.

Answer (score 8):

The victory in question was, of course the encounter in which the rebels managed to steal the Empire's plans for the Death Star.

We get a little more info about this encounter in the newly-released (and Disney-canon) Star Wars novelisation for [*A New Hope: The Princess, the Scoundrel, and the Farm Boy*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/A_New_Hope:_The_Princess,_the_Scoundrel,_and_the_Farm_Boy).

> Stealing top-secret plans from the Empire was a risk, but being
>   dismissed as a twinkling ball of gas had only made her more
>   determined. The mission should have been simple. All they needed to do
>   was intercept a transmission about a new battle station the Empire was
>   rumored to be building.
>
> But the system had been swarming with Imperials. They’d caught on to
>   Leia’s bogus tale about her ship’s breaking down, but the cover had
>   helped her stall long enough to download the technical plans for
>   something code-named “Death Star.” Despite the Rebels’ efforts to lose
>   the Imperials in the jump to hyperspace, the hulking Star Destroyer
>   had caught up to them. And Leia knew, the moment the ship identified
>   itself as the Devastator, there would be no escape.

---

Moving down the canon scale, the battle is referred to as the "[Battle of Orron III](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_of_Orron_III)" in the [*Star Wars: X-Wing*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_X-Wing) game, however it remains to be seen whether this will be incorporated in the upcoming [*Rogue One*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rogue_One) film which will act as a direct prequel to the events leading up to *A New Hope* and will detail the daring scheme to steal the plans for the Death Star.